# Real analysis Supremum and Infinum

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Let $S$ and $T$ be subsets of $\Bbb{R}$ such that $s < t$ for each $s ∈ S$ and each $t ∈ T$. Prove carefully that $\sup S ≤ \inf T$.

This question has been posted a few times, but I don't think the answers are formal enough

I start by using the definition for supremum and infinum, $\sup(S)= a$ and $\inf(T)= b$ 
and I know that $a> s$ and $b< t$ for all $s$ and $t$. How do I continue? Do I prove it directly starting from $s< t$ or will it be easier to use proof by contradiction?

Comment: Try to make a contradiction

Comment: You may begin so: consider the number line and prove that S stayed more left than T

Comment: We do NOT have  $\forall s\in S\; (\sup S=a>s).$ We have $\forall s\in S\;(\sup S=a\geq s). $  It is possible that $S$ has a maximum value. Similarly regarding $b$ and $ t$.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint*:

If s < t for all elements from S and T, then 
$S \cap T$ is empty. Now consider the number line and finish the proof.

Comment: Im still blank, im trying to start from s < t, hopefully i can end up with a string on inequalities and show sup(s) < inf (t)

Answer (score 0):

Let $a=\sup S$ and $b=\inf T$, as you suggested. When know that $s<t$ for all $s\in S,t\in T$. So, fix $t_{0}\in T$. Then, since $s<t_{0}$ for all $s\in S$, it must be that $a\leq t_{0}$; otherwise, by the definition of $\sup$, there would be an $s\in S$ such that $a\geq s>t$, which is impossible. Now, $t_{0}$ was chosen arbitrarily, so $a\leq t$ must hold for all $t\in T$. Hence, reasoning as above, it follows that $a\leq b$.

Comment: but b is not necessarily in T right? how do i get to  a ≤ b ?

Comment: It's true that $b$ is not necessarily in $T$, but $a\leq b$ is still true. Otherwise, if $a> b$, then by definition of $\sup$, there must be $t\in T$ such that $a>t>b$ (if not, then $b=\inf T\geq t>b$). This contradicts that $a\leq t$ for all $t\in T$

Answer (score 0):

Let $s\in S$ and $t\in T$ be arbitrary. By hypothesis, $s<t ≤\sup T$. Thus $\sup T$ is begger than or equal to all $s\in S$, so by definition of sup (the SMALESST upper bound), we must have $\sup S≤\sup T$.